# How to add more scales to x_axis by using 'axis' function?

Tags: r, plot, axis

This is a part of my dataset:
[Timestamps of this dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NQQUb.png)

This is my code:

```
par(mfrow=c(2,5),cex=0.5)
for (m in 3:12){
  plot(TPP13_output[,1][1:loops2],TPP13_output[,m][1:loops2],col=2,
       xlab=colnames(TPP13_output[1]),ylab=colnames(TPP13_output[m]))
}
```

And these are plots of this code:
[plots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xh3an.png)

As you can see, the scales on x_axis are very sparse and show little details of these timestamps. I want to make x_axis be more denser and shows details like '2020-11-19 17:00:00'. I know that 'at' argument of 'axis' function can help to achieve this, but 'Timestamp1' is a 'POSIXct' type, I do not know how to correctly set this argument to let it accept this type.

Comment: It is easier to provide a solution if you made a MWE. Using `dput(TPP13_output)` would help people see the data you are using.

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to provide a full answer without a reproducible example. However, here is some sample code for adding time axes with different resolutions. Basically, I don't plot the axis on the initial figure (`...axs='n'`) and add it separately with specific time resolution specified using the `seq()` function with the minimum time, maximum time, and time step (`by` argument in seconds) specified.

[image: Different Time Resolution x Axis]

```
# generate some random x and y values
x = as.POSIXlt("2017-02-03 08:00:00") + 100*rnorm(50, 0, 60*60)
y = cos(as.numeric(x)/(3600*25))+rnorm(length(x),0,0.3)

# making plots with different time steps
par(mfrow=c(3,1))
plot(x,y,
     xaxt='n',
     main='2 Days Ticks')
axis(side=1,
     at=seq(as.POSIXlt("2017-01-27 00:00:00"),as.POSIXlt("2017-02-9 23:59:59"),by=48*3600),
     labels = seq(as.POSIXlt("2017-01-27 00:00:00"),as.POSIXlt("2017-02-9 23:59:59"),by=48*3600)
     )

plot(x,y,
     xaxt='n',
     main='1 Day Ticks')
axis(side=1,
     at=seq(as.POSIXlt("2017-01-27 00:00:00"),as.POSIXlt("2017-02-9 23:59:59"),by=24*3600),
     labels = seq(as.POSIXlt("2017-01-27 00:00:00"),as.POSIXlt("2017-02-9 23:59:59"),by=24*3600)
)

plot(x,y,
     xaxt='n',
     main='12-Hour Ticks')
axis(side=1,
     at=seq(as.POSIXlt("2017-01-27 00:00:00"),as.POSIXlt("2017-02-9 23:59:59"),by=12*3600),
     labels = seq(as.POSIXlt("2017-01-27 00:00:00"),as.POSIXlt("2017-02-9 23:59:59"),by=12*3600)
)
```